# Strip all elements inside a specific element when descendant elements have same name as ancestor

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm using PHP and I would like to strip out all tags inside a specific tag and keep only plain text. The issue I'm stuck on is that there are some child tags that have the same name of the parents tags:

```
<corpo>
    <num>1.</num>
    <mod id="mod167">
        String 1
        <commas id="mod167-vir1" type="word">String 2</commas>
        <com id="mod166-vir1-20090024-art13-com16.1"><num>&lt;&lt;16.</num></com>
        <rif xlink:href="urn" xlink:type="simple">String 3</rif><h:p>Something here</h:p>
        <corpo>String 4</corpo>
   </mod>
</corpo>
```

Here, for example, `corpo` have a child tag with the same name (`<corpo>String 4</corpo>`) and the `num` tag is used two times (`<num>1.</num>` and `<num>&lt;&lt;16.</num>`) inside the parent tag `corpo`.

Starting from the highest `corpo` tag I would like to **strip out every child tag** and keep only the plain text. The result should be:

```
<corpo>
    String 1 String 2 &lt;&lt;16. String 3 Something here String 4
</corpo>
```

Up to now I tried with SimpleXML and the PHP `strip_tags` by adding all the tags I want to keep, but of course it does not give the result I expect.

```
$result = strip_tags($xml, "<corpo></corpo>";
```

Comment: You XML is invalid, you removed the namespace definitions (xmlns:*). Do you want to read the string, or do you really need to create a new xml?

Comment: The XML reported is an excerpt of a complex XML exported from a dB. I did not replicate the exact XML because I thought the problem could be solved with a regex as I simply need to read all the strings (plain text) inside the first `corpo` tag.

Comment: With XML the answer is almost never RegEx. If you remove the namespace definitions it changes and breaks the XML. Answers might not work, because information were missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *This is pretty related to what @ThW wrote, just more focussed on SimpleXML. Also I show some different angle on the xpath to select the corpo element(s).*

Given a document the same or with more ancestors as in your question as the string `$buffer` here is an example with XML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

foreach ($xml->xpath('//corpo[not(ancestor::corpo)]') as $corpo) {
    $corpo[0] = dom_import_simplexml($corpo)->textContent;
}

$xml->asXML('php://output');
```

An exemplary output of that is:

```
<a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:h="ns:h">
    <b>
        <corpo>
            1.

                String 1
                String 2

                    &lt;&lt;16.

                String 3
                Something here
                String 4

        </corpo>
    </b>
</a>
```

It works the following:

Get each *corpo* element that has no ancestor with that name. This is done by xpath:

```
//corpo[not(ancestor::corpo)]
```

Then as this is a **SimpleXMLElement** and you want the text-content, it is accesible through that's `$corpo` associated **DOMElement** node:

```
dom_import_simplexml($corpo)->textContent;
```

The remaining expression

```
$corpo[0] = ...
```

just tells to update the content of that **SimpleXMLElement** (so called self-reference).

BTW you could have used `strip_tags($corpo->asXML())` here instead of `dom_import_simplexml($corpo)->textContent` but I won't suggest that because I don't know how stable `strip_tags` really is. It's at least not XML standard conform.

Now you might want to apply some whitespace normalization as well, for that `preg_replace` is handy with the UTF-8 flag which is the string encoding used by **SimpleXMLElement** and **DOMElement**:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//corpo[not(ancestor::corpo)]') as $corpo) {
    $text     = dom_import_simplexml($corpo)->textContent;
    $corpo[0] = preg_replace('~\s+~u', ' ', $text);
}
```

This variant gives you:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:h="ns:h">
    <b>
        <corpo> 1. String 1 String 2 &lt;&lt;16. String 3 Something here String 4 </corpo>
    </b>
</a>
```

The full example at a glance [Demo](https://eval.in/395089):

```
<?php

$buffer = <<<XML
<a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:h="ns:h">
    <b>
        <corpo>
            <num>1.</num>
            <mod id="mod167">
                String 1
                <commas id="mod167-vir1" type="word">String 2</commas>
                <com id="mod166-vir1-20090024-art13-com16.1">
                    <num>&lt;&lt;16.</num>
                </com>
                <rif xlink:href="urn" xlink:type="simple">String 3</rif>
                <h:p>Something here</h:p>
                <corpo>String 4</corpo>
            </mod>
        </corpo>
    </b>
</a>
XML;


$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

foreach ($xml->xpath('//corpo[not(ancestor::corpo)]') as $corpo) {
    $text     = dom_import_simplexml($corpo)->textContent;
    $corpo[0] = preg_replace('~\s+~u', ' ', $text);
}

$xml->asXML('php://output');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you load the XML into DOM you can read the `DOMNode::$textContent` property.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);

var_dump($document->documentElement->textContent);
```

The output contains the text content including all whitespaces.

```
string(113) "
    1.

        String 1
        String 2
        <<16.
        String 3Something here
        String 4

"
```

In a more complex structure, use Xpath to fetch the value. The function `normalize-space()` casts the first node into a string, removes leading and trailing whitespaces and converts all other whitespace groups to a single space.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(/corpo)'));
```

Output:

```
string(58) "1. String 1 String 2 <<16. String 3Something here String 4"
```

To create a XML with the tags removed import the `corpo` node without children and append the text content:

```
$target = new DOMDocument();
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/corpo') as $corpo) {
  $target
    ->appendChild(
      $target->importNode($corpo)
    )->appendChild(
      $target->createTextNode(
        $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(.)', $corpo)
      )
    );
}

echo $target->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<corpo xmlns:xlink="urn:xlink" xmlns:h="urn:h">1. String 1 String 2 &lt;&lt;16. String 3Something here String 4</corpo>
```

Comment: You are pointing me on the right way, thanks, althought I still need some help. Your second approach is great. It assumes that 'corpo' is the root node (as I stated in my post), but actually it isn't. I get to it with the following: `$xml->xpath('//a:LeggeRegionale[@id="urn:nir:legge:2011-08-11;11"]/a:articolato/a:articolo[@id="art10"]');` How do I change your code accordingly?

Comment: It depends on the actual structure and namespace definitions. You will need to adapt the Xpath expressions. `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` however is limited, it can only return arrays of SimpleXMLElement instances, the example will only work with DOM. The second argument of `DOMXpath::evaluate()` is the context node for the expression.